# Redux Observable: How to dynamically map and call the same actions

Tags: javascript, observable

I am using react native redux `observable`, i want to return the same actions multiples times dynamically, but with different parameters passed.

**Error Message:**

> You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide
>   an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

I have already try `.from` `.map`. But it usually show this message

```
const getNewCategoryFullfilledEpic = (
  action$,
) => action$.pipe(
  ofType(MEMBER.GET_NEW_CATEGORY_FULFILLED),
  mergeMap((action) => {
     if (action.payload.data) {
      const { res } = action.payload.data;
        return of(
          MemberActions.getMemberOffer(0),
          MemberActions.getMemberOffer(1),
        );
    }
  })
);
```

Want to have this result: but dynamically generate up to how many parameters passed

```
return of(
          MemberActions.getMemberOffer(0),
          MemberActions.getMemberOffer(1),
        );
```

Which i tried to execute: ( I would like to map all the ids with calling the same actions, but it fails to do it ( error shown above )

```
res.map((item) => return of( MemberActions.getMemberOffer(item.id))}
```

Comment: Could you add comment where exactly do you get the error? Also show how you combine epics and how do you run() middleware. I don't think it's a problem connected to wrong rxjs version, but dependencies would be also helpful.

Comment: added some comments about my attempts, but fails. do u know how to call the same actions multiple times.. thank you so much. it really troubles me

Comment: I have few ideas. Think about it different - are these actions always dispatched together - if so why not make this state change as one action like ONE_AND_SECOND_ACTION. Or you can import dispatch and call it twice as side effect inside .map. First solution is more efficient.

Comment: ...less state mutations - less rerenders. First idea is the best.